# Getting info about a TLS connection in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, starttls

I'm successfully enabling encryption during an SMTP+STARTTLS transaction, but I'd like to find out some details about the TLS connection that was made. Encryption is enabled like this, after successfully opening the stream connection:

```
$encrypted = stream_socket_enable_crypto(
    $smtp_conn,
    true,
    STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT
);
```

`$encrypted` just contains `true`, which doesn't tell me much. I'm trying to find out where I can get at things like the TLS version, domain, public cert, key exchange mechanism, verification status, hash and cipher used in the connection. It must be a property of the stream the encryption is enabled on, so I've been looking in things like `stream_get_meta_data` but that only contains this:

```
[
    'timed_out' => false,
    'blocked' => true,
    'eof' => false,
    'stream_type' => 'tcp_socket/ssl',
    'mode' => 'r+',
    'unread_bytes' => 0,
    'seekable' => false,
]
```

I've also looked in `stream_context_get_params` and `stream_context_get_options` but neither contain anything interesting.

In NodeJS the place to look would be in [the TLS module](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket), which contains exactly the kind of things I'm looking for.

Where might I find more TLS info from PHP?